# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' although password is okay

Tags: mysql, shell, mariadb, debian, access-denied

I run Debian 11 with mariadb and everything worked fine. Just yesterday I saw that different commands, such as `/etc/init.d/mariadb reload` or `mysql -u root` bring the error:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using
> password: NO)

But I can log in with `mysql -u root -p xxx`.

The password seems to be okay:

> SELECT User, Host, authentication_string,plugin FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root';

brings this output:

```
| root | localhost    | *A1500BDAC90A8E0183B2803086BD6D6E0999EC60 | mysql_native_password |
| root | ::1          | *A1500BDAC90A8E0183B2803086BD6D6E0999EC60 | mysql_native_password |
| root | myserver     | *A1500BDAC90A8E0183B2803086BD6D6E0999EC60 | mysql_native_password |
| root | 127.0.0.1    | *A1500BDAC90A8E0183B2803086BD6D6E0999EC60 | mysql_native_password |
```

What I don't understand: with the plugin `mysql_native_password` and the set password I should be able to login with `mysql -u root`, for instance.
`bind-address` is set to `0.0.0.0`.

MySQL (MariaDB) runs on the server, all the websites can access it without any errors. Just Debian can't access it. Any ideas?

---

#### Edit:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
```

brings these 3 rows:

```
Row 1: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A1500BDAC90A8E0183B2803086BD6D6E0999EC60' WITH GRANT OPTION

Row 2: GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
Row 3: GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Don't I need any `unix_socket` in there? But how?

---

#### Edit 2:

I think I know the problem:
The upper-mentioned privileges for `root@localhost` look like the syntax of an old MySQL version. I use mariadb von Debian 11. I guess, I mistakenly overtook the export of the privileges of root 1 by 1 from the old system to the new.

The question is just: how should it look right?

I looked on another server with Debian 11 where it runs. There the privileges are like that:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA
mysql_native_password USING
'*84A00BCFE90A8E0183B2803086BD6D6E0999EC12' OR unix_socket WITH GRANT
OPTION
```

Can I try that without risking locking myself out totally? Again: the webserver with all the MySQL databases runs fine. Should I try to run that line, just with the correct password hash, of course?
Thank you!

Comment: *ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: **NO**)* - this means that you do NOT provide the information that the password is needed. This is true - in your command line `mysql -u root` there is no `-p` or `--password=` key. So adjust your command line.

Comment: As mentioned, I can log in with the "-p" parameter. But the problem is that I can't reload mariadb anymore by "/etc/init.d/mariadb reload" (also other operations like that. I guess also restart/start would not work), as the login without "-p" doesn't work, brings the "access denied" error. I guess I need to allow any socket connection for root@localhost. But I have not idea how. Any ideas?

Comment: The password is NOT empty. So the option `-p` or `--password=` MUST present in either command line or (preferred) in the options file (my.ini).

Comment: on a fresh install of debian 11, I can login to mariadb just with "mysql -u root" without the "-p" parameter. this also worked on this server in the past. for any reason it doesn't work anymore. this is why e.g. "/etc/init.d/mariadb reload" and also other mysql operations, done by debian, don't work anymore. they bring the error "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

As it is debian, there is no mysql.ini, but a myql.cnf inside /etc/mysql/. But the configurations there look fine. I guess it is a problem with the privilegs of root@localhost ?

Comment: I think I have to bring in "unix_socket" in any way, so that debian has access without password. just for having access at "/etc/init.d/mariadb reload" and other system side calls to mysql. but I don't know how?

Comment: `ALTER USER \`root\`@\`localhost\` IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket`

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved!

As no one confirmed that it would work as mentioned in "Edit 2", I risked it now and gave it a try. By running the mysql command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA
mysql_native_password USING
'*84A00BCFE90A8E0183B2803086BD6D6E0999EC12' OR unix_socket WITH GRANT
OPTION
```

... I got it to run again. The debian root has passwordless access to mysql root now again.

I hope that helps anyone out there who faces the same problem. Just get sure to replace the hash '*84A00BCFE90A8E0183B2803086BD6D6E0999EC12' by your own one, depending on your password!